# make one common view class with xib for all viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, view, uiviewcontroller, uitabview

I have 5 tabs in my iphone app, each tab have  different `viewcontrollers` inside and I want to show & hide one common `view` (not `viewcontroller`) for all tabs and `viewcontrollers`.

I can make one common class for that, then how can i show the view from different classes by setting its frame  .I have tried by presenting a common  `viewcontroller` and a view inside it, but when i trying to show it, it shows a black screen,  Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You can add your view to window in AppDelegate

Comment: @ThilinaCháminHewagama; if the view is not programmatically created?

Comment: I'd create a base view controller with the option to opt that in (but the window can be an option to depending on the app architecture). The view itself should have it's own .xib file but then it's programmatically added (and not created).

Comment: When you want to show common view ? On tab change or in particular method of respective view controller? Please show your code, how did you present common controller?

Comment: @mvp, if the view is not programmatically created. how do you design the view ? , xib or storyboard ?

Comment: @ThilinaCháminHewagama; it is xib.

Comment: Create a viewcontroller with a .xib file, design your view in the xib properly. 
ABCViewController.h
ABCViewController.m
ABCViewController.xib
Then, in AppDelegate, create an instance from ABCViewController using initWithNibName, add the viewcontroller's view as a subview to the window.

Comment: @ThilinaCháminHewagama: yes, that s a point. but how how can call it from my viewcontroller.

Comment: add a reference to your vc in AppDelegate,

@property (nonatomic, strong) ABCViewController *abcViewController;


- (void) showExtraView{
 if (_abcViewController == nil){
  _abcViewController = [[ABCViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ABCViewController" bundle:nil];
 } 
 [self.window addSubview:_abcViewController.view];
}

-(void)hideExtraView{
 [_abcViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
}
call AppDelegate's method from your view controller witch is in the tab

Comment: @ThilinaCháminHewagama: Thank you so much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84669/discussion-between-mvp-and-thilina-chamin-hewagama).